# I have a form and a button to add duplicates of it. I want the duplicate radio inputs to have variable names

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 'count' variable in my javascript which increments each time a new form is added. Currently, I'm trying this:

```
count=1;
function newForm(){
...<input name=""check"+count" type="radio" value="Website" />...
}
```

But, obviously that's not working.

Comment: You need to learn about the DOM.

Comment: `name="check"+count`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use " quotes like you have enclose you "(double quote) in '(single quote)

Change it to

```
<input name='"check'+count+'"' type="radio" value="Website" />
```